# Modals in React 0.13

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I am using React 0.13 and I can not change to another version.

I am trying to place a Bootstrap Modal within my page.
However, whenever I try to install a node package which creates modals, I get an error saying that the package only works with React 0.14

I have tried all the packages listed here:
http://reactjsnews.com/modals-in-react

What else can I try?

Is there any package which works with React 0.13?

Can I somehow get a previous version of one of these packages which works with React 0.13?

Comment: You could always downgrade to a version where React 0.13 was used.

Comment: Out of interest why can't you upgrade? The breaking changes are pretty minor - Or do you have a third party dep which needs it?

Comment: I am currently working on a project that uses React Bootstrap 0.25.2 modals with React 0.13.3.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but, what you can do is:

1. Open the Github page of the one of the packages (e.g. https://github.com/rackt/react-modal)
2. Open up package.json (https://github.com/rackt/react-modal/blob/master/package.json)
3. Scroll down to where it says `peerDependencies` (you will see something like: `"react": "^0.14.0"` which means it is only compatible with React version 0.14).
4. Click at the top of the page where it says `Branch: master` then click on `tags`
5. Select an earlier tag and scroll down to `peerDependencies` again until you find one which says something like `"react": "^0.13.0"`. (in this case the tag 0.5.0 has the peer dependency of `"react": ">=0.13.3 || ^0.14.0-beta3"` which means it will work with React 0.13).
6. In your own `package.json` file, add: `"react-modal": "^0.5.0"` to your dependencies and then run `npm install`